# how to insert data to the database table with hook_update_N

Tags: hooks

i have just create a table inside the file mymodule.install , the database was created successfully but not for the hook_update_N , 8001,8002 and 8003 , they tell me **'[success] No pending updates.'** so the hook hook_update_N , 8001,8002 and 8003 does not insert anything

can anyone tell me why please ?

this is my code

```
/**
 * Installs the database schema.
 */
function mymodule_install() {
  drupal_install_schema('mymodule_post');
}

/**
 * Uninstalls the database schema.
 */
function mymodule_uninstall() {
  drupal_uninstall_schema('mymodule_post');
}

/**
* Creates the tables using the schema API.
*/
function mymodule_schema() {
  $schema['mymodule_post'] = array(
    'description' => 'description ',
    'fields' => array(
      'pid' => array(
        'description' => 'post id',
        'type' => 'serial',
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'title' => array(
        'description' => 'title',
        'type' => 'text',
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'body' => array(
        'description' => 'body',
        'type' => 'text',
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'created' => array(
              'description' => 'created',
              'not null' => TRUE,
              'mysql_type' => 'timestamp',
            ),
    ),
    'primary key' => ['pid'],
  );
  return $schema;
}


function mymodule_update_8001() {

  //some codes
}


function mymodule_update_8002() {

  //some codes
}


function mymodule_update_8003() {
 //some codes
}
?>
```

Comment: You're using Drupal 6 code but numbering your updates as if you're using Drupal 8...

Comment: Really !! , can you show me the code for drupal 8 please

Comment: Just remove the hook_install and hook_uninstall functions, they're not necessary (but also probably not causing your immediate problem). For that, check the module's current schema version with `drush ev "print drupal_get_installed_schema_version('mymodule');"` and see what current state it's in. Seems likely the current installed version is somehow greater than 8001/8002/8003, as your code looks otherwise fine

Comment: current state it's on 8003%

Comment: Yup, so it's not going to run 8003 again because it's already done it. Use `drupal_set_installed_schema_version` to reset it

Comment: yes thanks it works now , where can i find this '8003' inside my database to change it without this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to copy the table definition in a `hook_update_n` implementation. You can see an example of the this in 8.9.x Layout Builder layout_builder.install file.
https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/8.9.x/core/modules/layout_builder/layout_builder.install#L68

```
/**
 * Implements hook_schema().
 */
function layout_builder_schema() {
  $schema['inline_block_usage'] = [
    'description' => 'Track where a block_content entity is used.',
    'fields' => [
      'block_content_id' => [
        'description' => 'The block_content entity ID.',
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ],
      'layout_entity_type' => [
        'description' => 'The entity type of the parent entity.',
        'type' => 'varchar_ascii',
        'length' => EntityTypeInterface::ID_MAX_LENGTH,
        'not null' => FALSE,
        'default' => '',
      ],
      'layout_entity_id' => [
        'description' => 'The ID of the parent entity.',
        'type' => 'varchar_ascii',
        'length' => 128,
        'not null' => FALSE,
        'default' => 0,
      ],
    ],
    'primary key' => ['block_content_id'],
    'indexes' => [
      'type_id' => ['layout_entity_type', 'layout_entity_id'],
    ],
  ];
  return $schema;
}

/**
 * Create the 'inline_block_usage' table.
 */
function layout_builder_update_8602() {
  $inline_block_usage = [
    'description' => 'Track where a block_content entity is used.',
    'fields' => [
      'block_content_id' => [
        'description' => 'The block_content entity ID.',
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ],
      'layout_entity_type' => [
        'description' => 'The entity type of the parent entity.',
        'type' => 'varchar_ascii',
        'length' => EntityTypeInterface::ID_MAX_LENGTH,
        'not null' => FALSE,
        'default' => '',
      ],
      'layout_entity_id' => [
        'description' => 'The ID of the parent entity.',
        'type' => 'varchar_ascii',
        'length' => 128,
        'not null' => FALSE,
        'default' => 0,
      ],
    ],
    'primary key' => ['block_content_id'],
    'indexes' => [
      'type_id' => ['layout_entity_type', 'layout_entity_id'],
    ],
  ];
  Database::getConnection()->schema()->createTable('inline_block_usage', $inline_block_usage);
}
```

See the `inline_block_usage` definition is the same in `layout_builder_schema()` and  `layout_builder_update_8602()`.

`layout_builder_update_8602()` manually creates the table via
`Database::getConnection()->schema()->createTable('inline_block_usage', $inline_block_usage);`